# How can I json_decode multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I try to make an array from this stringifyed json.

```
$str_json = '{"name":"name","value":"max"},{"name":"surname","value":"mustermann"}';
$arr_json = json_decode($str_json, true);

print_r($arr_json);
```

From these code i get nothing back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because that isn't valid JSON.

To create an array, you need to surround your data with `[ ]`.

```
$str_json = '[{"name":"name","value":"max"},{"name":"surname","value":"mustermann"}]';
$arr_json = json_decode($str_json, true);
print_r($arr_json);
```

For future reference, you can always validate your JSON with services such as [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Nice! Thank you! that's it. :-)